# errors when using apiKey for sentinel2 10 landcover

Tags: angular, arcgis, sentinel2

i have arcgis developer account and apiKey, i try to use the https://env1.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Sentinel2_10m_LandCover/ImageServer, but get error showing invalid token.
i wonder how can i test with the https://env1.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Sentinel2_10m_LandCover/ImageServer ImageryLayer?

raster layer https://env1.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Sentinel2_10m_LandCover/ImageServer

That i want to display in my angular 14 app, i have successly used feature layer and basemap.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.